# Query dsl projections for inhertience types

Tags: querydsl

I have three classes like Vehicle as base type and Car and Bike are inherting the Vehicle class.

Problem is I want to get all the Vehicles using query dsl and conditions for vehicles are

- Car object should be filled with brand and totalDoor fileds (not any other)
- Bike object should be filled with brand field only (not any other).

Vehicle class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="vehicles")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Vehicle {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id", length = 30)
  private Integer id;
  private String brand;  
  private String color;

  public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
  }

  public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
  }

  public String getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

*Car class*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cars")
public class Car extends Vehicle {
  private int totalDoor;
  private int numeberofSeats;

  public int getTotalDoor() {
    return totalDoor;
  }

  public void setTotalDoor(int totalDoor) {
    this.totalDoor = totalDoor;
  }

  public int getNumeberofSeats() {
    return numeberofSeats;
  }

  public void setNumeberofSeats(int numeberofSeats) {
    this.numeberofSeats = numeberofSeats;
  }
}
```

*Bike class*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bikes")
public class Bike extends Vehicle {
  private int numerberOfTiers;

  public int getNumerberOfTiers() {
    return numerberOfTiers;
  }

  public void setNumerberOfTiers(int numerberOfTiers) {
    this.numerberOfTiers = numerberOfTiers;
  }
}
```

Query for all vehicles but where to specify the Car and Bike Projections?

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = new JPAQuery(manager)
    .from(vehicle)
    .distinct()
    .list(Projections.bean(Vehicle.class , vehicle.brand));
```

Comment: Could you explain why the default population for Car and Bike don't work for you?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Default population for Car and Bike will work. But, is there any way to get only selected fields from Car and bike objects as List<Vehicle> using above query ?

Answer (score 1):

You can populate specific subtypes in separate queries, but not in one query. So you can either specific separate queries for the subtypes or post process the results.